# Equivalent of VertX CompositeFuture in RxJava

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming, vert.x

The VertX example for when you need to query multiple asynchronous resources and use them all in a single operation is:

```
Future<HttpServer> httpServerFuture = Future.future();
httpServer.listen(httpServerFuture.completer());

Future<NetServer> netServerFuture = Future.future();
netServer.listen(netServerFuture.completer());

CompositeFuture.all(httpServerFuture, netServerFuture).setHandler(ar -> {
  if (ar.succeeded()) {
    // All servers started
  } else {
    // At least one server failed
  }
});
```

We need to query two different databases and then use the results in business logic, but the flow is equivalent.

What's the VertX/RxJava equivalent?

Currently people are doing this by nesting a new .flatMap() call every time they need a new variable. I'm left feeling there must be a better way...

We don't actually need the queries to be concurrent but we need to cache both results and pass them to the business logic at the same time some how.

Comment: Can you use `CompletableFuture.allOf(CompleatableFuture<?>...): CompletableFuture<Void>`? This would be standard Java 8.

Comment: How would you use that in the context of VertX/RxJava?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by "in the context of" and in fact I do not know why Vert.x still has its own futures even after moving to Java 8. But you can complete a `CompletableFuture`s in  asynchronous vertx callbacks and then run `...allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0])).thenApply($ -> (action on success)).exceptionally(t -> (action on exception if needed))` that is just standard `CompletableFuture` operations. Given it is all async you should be able to do the same with RxJava as long as you know how which future to complete.

Answer (score 1):

there are many ways to do this, but i've tried to pick an approach that tacks closely to your sample:

```
@Override
public void start(Future<Void> startFuture) throws Exception {
    final HttpServer httpServer = vertx.createHttpServer();
    final Completable initializeHttpServer = httpServer.rxListen().toCompletable();

    final NetServer netServer = vertx.createNetServer();
    final Completable initializeNetServer = netServer.rxListen().toCompletable();

    initializeHttpServer.andThen(initializeNetServer)
        .subscribe(
            ()    -> { /* All servers started */ },
            error -> { /* At least one server failed */ }
        );
}
```

the `rxListen()` invocations are converted into `Completable` instances, which are then run serially upon subscription.

- the subscriber's `onComplete` callback will be invoked when both servers are done binding to their respective ports, or...
- the `onError` callback will be invoked if an exception occurs

(also, fwiw, "nesting" `flatMap` operations for something as trivial as this shouldn't be necessary. "chaining" such operations, however, would be idiomatic usage).

hope that helps!

**--UPDATE--**

having read the question more carefully, i now see that you were actually asking about how to handle the results of two discrete asynchronous operations.

an alternative to `flatMap`'ing your way to combining the results would be to use the `zip` operator, like so:

```
    @Override
    public void start(Future<Void> startFuture) throws Exception {
        final Single<String> dbQuery1 = Single.fromCallable(() -> { return "db-query-result-1"; });
        final Single<String> dbQuery2 = Single.fromCallable(() -> { return "db-query-result-2"; });

        Single.zip(dbQuery1, dbQuery2, (result1, result2) -> {
            // handle the results from both db queries
            // (with Pair being a standard tuple-like class)
           return new Pair(result1, result2);
        })
            .subscribe(
                pair -> {
                    // handle the results
                },
                error -> {
                    // something went wrong
                }
            );
    }
```

per the [docs](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Single.html#zip-io.reactivex.SingleSource-io.reactivex.SingleSource-io.reactivex.functions.BiFunction-), `zip` allows you to specify a series of reactive types (`Single`, `Observable`, etc) along with a function to transform all the results at once, with the central idea being that it will not emit anything until all the sources have emitted once (or more, depending on the reactive type).